# AutoMapper - Use method to update IEnumerable property with no setter?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm having some trouble using AutoMapper to map from a data transfer object to a database entity model. The entity has a few properties that are custom array types, derived from IEnumerable. There's no setter for those properties, but there is a method called `SetFromString()` that is available. I can't seem to configure my map properly to use it though. Does AutoMapper support this kind of thing? If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Below is a boiled-down version of the key classes I'm working with. (The mapping works just fine going from entity to DTO, but I need it to work in the reverse direction as well.)

```
// The database entity
public class ContactEntity
{
    public CustomArray<String> CustomerNumbers { get; }
}

// The data transfer object
public class ContactDto
{
    public List<String> CustomerNumbers { get; set; }
}

// CustomArray definition
public abstract class CustomArray<DataType> : IEnumerable<DataType>, IDisposable
{
    protected CustomArray();
    public abstract void SetFromString(string Value);
}
```

My mapping profile is still pretty vanilla since I couldn't wrap my head around the proper `ForMember` syntax.

```
public class ContactMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public ContactMappingProfile()
    {
        // This map works fine
        CreateMap<ContactEntity, ContactDto>();

        // Map from DTO to Entity            
        CreateMap<ContactDto, ContactEntity>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerNumbers,
                opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.CustomerNumbers));
    }
}
```

Thanks again for any help you can provide!

Comment: If you were doing it manually, how would you convert `List<String>` to `string Value` needed for `SetFromString` method?

Comment: For simplicity, let's say the string needs to be comma separated. For that, my code would look like this `string.Join(",", src.CustomerNumbers);`. The part that I'm missing is how to pass that value to `dest.CustomerNumbers.SetFromString();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use either `UseDestinationValue` or `Ignore` for destination entity `CustomerNumbers` member and perform the actual mapping in `AfterMap`:

```
cfg.CreateMap<ContactDto, ContactEntity>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerNumbers, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.CustomerNumbers.SetFromString(string.Join(",", src.CustomerNumbers)));
```